# Wrapfigure issue of table & figure in 1 line

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure

I tried to use wrapfig package to arrange a small table in the left & a figure in the right in 1 line while text floats around them but failed.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}          
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,intersections,through}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{l}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}
\hline Score & Teacher  \\[-0.5mm]
\hline & \\[3mm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scriptsize}
\coordinate [label=-135:{$A$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=-45:{$B$}] (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate [label=0:{$C$}] (C) at ($(3,0)+(60:3)$);
\coordinate [label=135:{$D$}] (D) at (60:3);
\coordinate [label=-90:{$E$}] (E) at (2.7,0);
\coordinate [label=180:{$F$}] (F) at (60:2);
\coordinate [label=0:{$G$}] (G) at ($(B)!(F)!(C)$);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\draw (E)--(F)--(G);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

The output is as:
[image: wrap]

Any idea on how to let the table & figure align horizontally while text still floats around them?

Comment: Package `wrapfig` supports only one figure/table at a time. I don't know of any package that supports two the way you want. It might be possible to do it by hand, but probably only with a lot of work measuring, retrying, measuring again, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`wrapfig` doesn't really support two figures on the same line, but if we simplify things and just look at the case where there is a single paragraph that is large enough for the cutouts, and we don't have to do the clever continuation paragraph code that `wrapfig` does, then you can simply measure the two images and make a `\parshape` that fits around them.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum,capt-of}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}          
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,intersections,through}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}
\hline Score & Teacher  \\[-0.5mm]
\hline & \\[3mm]
\hline
\end{tabular}}



\sbox2{\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scriptsize}
\coordinate [label=-135:{$A$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=-45:{$B$}] (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate [label=0:{$C$}] (C) at ($(3,0)+(60:3)$);
\coordinate [label=135:{$D$}] (D) at (60:3);
\coordinate [label=-90:{$E$}] (E) at (2.7,0);
\coordinate [label=180:{$F$}] (F) at (60:2);
\coordinate [label=0:{$G$}] (G) at ($(B)!(F)!(C)$);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\draw (E)--(F)--(G);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}}

\dimen4=\dimexpr\wd0 + 1em\relax
\dimen0=\textwidth
\advance\dimen0-\dimexpr\wd2 + 1em\relax
\dimen2=\dimen0
\advance\dimen2-\dimexpr\wd0 + 1em\relax

\noindent
\smash{\hbox to \textwidth{%
\raisebox{-\height}{\box0}\hfill
\raisebox{-\height}{\box2}}}\par\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\emergencystretch{1em}
\parshape
10
\dimen4  \dimen2
\dimen4  \dimen2
\dimen4  \dimen2
\dimen4  \dimen2
0pt      \dimen0
0pt      \dimen0
0pt      \dimen0
0pt      \dimen0
0pt      \dimen0
0pt      \textwidth
\lipsum[1-4]


\end{document}
```